# Error while trying to set a slot of a cl-struct

Tags: common-lisp

Using Emacs 25.1.50.1

To set the slot of a structure, I believe the elisp manual says to use `setq` along with the accessor function for the slot. Though I am having trouble.

The following code results in an error on the fourth line.

```
(require 'cl)
(cl-defstruct foo name)
(setq bar (make-foo :name 'john))
(setq (foo-name bar) 'jim)
```

Message:

eval: Wrong type argument: symbolp, (progn "Access slot \"name\" of    `foo' struct CL-X." nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp bar) (>= (length bar) 2) (memq (aref bar 0) cl-struct-foo-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote foo) bar))) (aref bar 1))

Also there is no `cl` tag to use for the Emacs Common Lisp Emulation Library... don't know what else to put it under, just going to put it under `common-lisp` for someone to help me find the *right* tag.

Comment: You need to use `setf` instead of `setq`.

Comment: Oh, I was not seeing a difference... though now it seems perfectly clear, thank you.

Comment: @syohex, you should make that an answer.

Comment: Answered as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setf` instead of `setq`.

```
(setf (foo-name bar) 'jim)
```